# Matrix addition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, arithmetic, vectors

How do I solve the following?

[2x1 -3x2 + x3; 4x1 - 2x3] + [x1 +2x2; 0x1 - 2x2; 4x1 + x2]^T

When I do the transpose of the second matrix and try to add them together I get lost. Should I consider x1 +2x2 of matrix 2 as one component when getting its transpose? Or are they two separate components? For example:
Would getting the transpose of matrix 2 lead to a new matrix with only 1 row or 2?

Edit: more information

The problem is to compute the linear transformation T(A+C^T)([2;1;1])

We are given matrix A and C
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
2& -3 &1\\ 
4& 0& -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

C=[1 2; 0 -2; 4 1]

I computed the matrix transformation induced by A, Ax, and the matrix transformation induced by C, Cx, as previously shown above.

Comment: As stated your problem doesn't make sense, you are trying to add a $2\times 1$ matrix to a $1\times 3$ matrix.

Comment: What are you trying to add these two matrices? Perhaps you could give us some more context.

Comment: Also, please format your question properly.  For a tutorial on how to do so, look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  In particular, see the section on [matrices](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5023/81360) and use the `bmatrix` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you found the product $Cx$ incorrectly.  In fact, these multiplication is invalid because the dimensions don't match.

Instead, find $C^Tx$ by taking the transpose of $C$ **first**, then multiplying it by $x$.

The easier approach, however, is to add $A + C^T$ and then multiply the result by $x$ to find $(A + C^T)x$ directly.

Comment: If we have our vector x in Cx be [x1; x2] then x is a 2x1 matrix. C is a 3x2 matrix. The dimension to multiply them should be 2x(#) and the resulting dimension, according to C and x should be 3x1, which is what Cx= [x1 +2x2; 0x1 - 2x2; 4x1 + x2] is. I am not sure how the dimensions do not match.

Comment: The vector $x$ can't be different when you multiply it by $A$ and when you multiply it by $C$. In this case, $x$ is always $3 \times 1$

Comment: In fact, in this case $x$ is always $x = \pmatrix{2\\1\\1}$.  We can't just magically make it into a $2 \times 1$ matrix